# OpenGL Version not Supported for IntelliJ on Mac

Tags: java, intellij-idea, opengl, glsl, version

I've been trying to learn glsl with OpenGL on IntelliJ and have been running into a few problems. First of my issues is with the #version.

```
#type vertex
#version 460

layout (location=0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location=1) in vec4 aColor;

out vec4 fColor;

void main(){
    fColor = aColor;
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0);
}
```

when I try to run this with my java in my java program I get an error message:

```
"ERROR: 0:1: '' :  version '460' is not supported"\
```

Even though when I looked up my graphics chip (Intel Iris Graphics 550) it says it supports the openGL 4.60 API.

I put:

```
System.out.println(glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION));
```

which returns 1.20, and I'm not sure if I can get that to change to my needed 4.6 some how.

I believe that is also why I am receive my other error message which is:

```
"ERROR: 0:3: 'layout' : syntax error: syntax error"
```

I've tried a few things like having the extensions:

```
#extension GL_ARB_explicit_attribute_location : require
#extension GL_ARB_explicit_uniform_location : require
```

but then I just get "not supported" errors for those as well.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

If you need more info about the code I'm working on I've just been trying to follow a [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=025QFeZfeyM&t=5806s) at
around 1:36:00-1:46:00

EDIT:

Here is where I initialized the OpenGL context:

```
//initialize GLFW
if(!glfwInit()){
   throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to initialize GLFW.");
}

//configure GLFW
glfwDefaultWindowHints();
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GLFW_FALSE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_TRUE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_MAXIMIZED, GLFW_TRUE);

//create the window
glfwWindow = glfwCreateWindow(this.width, this.height, this.title, NULL, NULL);
if(glfwWindow == NULL) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to create the window.");
}

glfwSetCursorPosCallback(glfwWindow, MouseListener::mousePosCallback);
glfwSetMouseButtonCallback(glfwWindow, MouseListener::mouseButtonCallback);
glfwSetScrollCallback(glfwWindow, MouseListener::mouseScrollCallback);
glfwSetKeyCallback(glfwWindow, KeyListener::keyCallback);
//make the OpenGl context current
glfwMakeContextCurrent(glfwWindow);
//Enable v-sync (buffer swapping)
glfwSwapInterval(1);

//Make window Visible
glfwShowWindow(glfwWindow);

GL.createCapabilities();
```

Comment: As far as I'm aware mac os only supports up to OpenGL 4.1.  Please show your code that creates and initializes the OpenGL context or, if possible, a [mcve],

Comment: .. .You cannot use OpenGL 4.6 / `GLSL 460` on a Mac. You must downgrade to a OpenGL 4.1 Core profile and `GLSL 410 core`.

Comment: @G.M. what I have is an initialization and the I do a few windowhints and set up the callbacks, and then to create the context with the window I just do glfwMakeContextCurrent(glfwWindow);

Comment: @Rabbid76 hey sorry did you know how I can do that?

Comment: Where and how do you create the OpenGL window?

Comment: Re. `"...I do a few windowhints and set up the callbacks, and then to create the context with the window I just do glfwMakeContextCurrent(glfwWindow)"`: you need to *show* the code rather than trying to describe it.

Comment: @G.M. sorry about that, I've edited the post to contain my context set up

Comment: @Rabbid76 i added it to the post for my initialization, I also added `GLFW.glfwWindowHint(GLFW.GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
    GLFW.glfwWindowHint(GLFW.GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 1);` which made it so when I print version it prints version 4.10

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got it to work by adding

```
GLFW.glfwWindowHint(GLFW.GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
GLFW.glfwWindowHint(GLFW.GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
```

after my other window hints when I am initializing my context for my OpenGL window. then I changed the version in my .glsl file back to

```
#version 330 core
```

this also fixed my issue I had with the layout().

Comment: I highly doubt that, because layouts were not available in 330.